# Why is the sqlite3 module in python creating all databases in only one directory?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am trying to work with the sqlite3 module in python, and no matter where my python file is stored - the 'example.db' is always stored in one specific directory. I have created different python files at different directories - but the 'example.db' is always stored at the same path.

I googled and read that with

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
```

the database should be created in the directory where the python file is stored.
Any guesses why that is not the case? Thank you for any advice.

Comment: What "same path" is that? Is it your current directory?

Comment: Relative pathnames are interpreted from the user's working directory, not the script directory.

Comment: Try giving a full absolute path!

Comment: All '.db's have been created in "/Users/Nikita/test_db"
I thought the current directory is the one of the terminal in vsCode. After changing it and running the python script the cwd in the terminal switched allways to "/Users/Nikita/test_db".
However, I found that with creating a launch.json file at "Run and Debug" in vsCode, I can change the working directory with "cwd": "my path to db".
Is there any other way to specify my current working directory?